# Loading two versions of React with Module Federation - without control of host

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

I'm writing a plugin to a system that uses Module Federation to load plugin code into the main framework dynamically. So I can define the module federation config for the remote, but I don't have control of the host.

The host uses React 17, whereas my plugin code (which is adapted from an existing codebase) uses React 18 and I don't want to downgrade.

I would like to import the shared React 17 library from the host and use it to create a new React 18 root under which I can render the plugin.

For example:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react-shared";      // <-- Somehow load shared React 17 from host

import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client"; // Import React 18 to create new root

export default function PluginEntry() {        // React 17 component that is rendered by the host
    useEffect(() => {                          // This useEffect must be the shared React 17 version to work properly
        const container = document.getElementById("plugin-root");
        const root = createRoot(container);
        root.render(<PluginApp />);            // PluginApp code will import "react" and expect React 18

        return () => { root.unmount(); }
    }, []);

    return <div id="plugin-root"></div>
}
```

The part that I'm missing is how to import the react library from the host without it overriding the react library imported everywhere else in the plugin, keeping in mind that I don't have access to the webpack config on the host.

Comment: Have you ever figured out the answer to this question?